# TYPO3 9.5: put a custom-path segment after language / route enhancers

Tags: routes, migration, typo3, typo3-9.x, realurl

Migrating von TYPO3 8.7 to 9.5 I need to replace an old realurl-configuration to match the new routing:

Old-Realurl Config: Custom Segment for Country after language:

```
'preVars' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'en' => '0', // darf nicht auskommentiert sein!
                'de' => '1',
                'pl' => '2',
                ...

        array(
            'GETvar' => 'C',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'de'=>'1',
                'ch'=>'2',
                'ch'=>'3',
```

I tried "simple" route enhancer inTYPO3 9.5 Site Config:

```
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-us
    direction: ltr
    flag: us
  -
    title: German
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: '1'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
routeEnhancers:
  Country:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '/{Country}'
    defaults:
    requirements:
      C: '[1-21]'
    aspects:
      Country:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:             
          de: 1
          ch: 2
```

But the country segments wont appear between Language and main-slug:
OLD URLS:
www.mydomain.com/de/ch/home/

With my rout-enhancer config (above):
www.mydomain.com/de/home/ch/

Does anyone know how I can achive this custom segment and let it appear at the right place ?

Many Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A route enhancer adds something after the Page URL. However, we had a similar scenario. Here is what I had to do in order to make it work:

### Getting to the right link:

#### 1. Resolving an incoming page request

Build a custom middleware (after the language is resolved, and a SiteRouteResult is available in the PSR-7 Request in a PSR-15 middleware)
This middleware then takes the "tail" of the SiteRouteResult, and resolves the argument based on a given static list (like it was available in the list). After that, I created a new SiteRouteResult object with that pathSegment removed from the tail.
Keep in mind that it might be very useful to store the resolved argument as a "variant" of the page, thus, effectively hooking into TSFE where the createHashBase() is built to also calculate in this variable.

I recommend storing this string in the request as custom property, or as a custom TSFE property.

It is NOT possible to resolve a "prePathVar" with a RouteEnhancer, as the right route enhancers are only selected AFTER the page was found. If your URL has "/ch/home" TYPO3 PageRouter can NOT find the correct page.

#### 2. Creating links with the "&c" query parameter

Create a RouteEnhancer that acts like a decorator (see PageType enhancer). However, the decorator does not need does not "undecorate" / "resolve" an URL (do nothing).
 This gets tricky if you also use the PageTypeDecorator, as you can only have one, so you might need to extend the one from Core, if you also need to map typeNums.

In any case, the custom Enhancer can then prefix the generated route with the static map depending if the type is given.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This gives me a good idea of what has to be done. Even though it might be a bit hard for me as typo3-integrator to achive it. If anybody like to post coding examples - very welcome ! Meanwhile I started reading about "middelwares": https://usetypo3.com/psr15-middleware-in-typo3.html

Comment: I managed to create a customPageTypeDecorator: in all generated links the "&C=..." is encoded at the right place after language.
I also managed to create a middleware and to create a new SiteRouteResult with updated path.
Basically it works, so far.

But I have Problems in "hooking into TSFE where the createHashBase() is built".
I think I need different cached versions of the page depending on different C-Parameters.
Is it a difficult task or could it be done with a few lines of Code ?
Any Extension-Recommendations where I could find the basics ?

Comment: You can do this by registering a hook in your ext_localconf.php like this extension does it:

https://github.com/sourcebroker/singleview/blob/master/ext_localconf.php#L22-L23


The hook then could look like this by modifying the $params['hashParameters']['country'] = 'My Value';

 
 
 https://github.com/sourcebroker/singleview/blob/master/Classes/Hooks/HashBase.php

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Finally all worked out very nice. I put all 3 parts (custom PageTypeDecorator, PSR-15 middleware and Hook for Caching the custom-parameter) into one extension. When I cleaned up my extension a bit, I will put it on GITlab and link it from here to share with community ;-) Cheers

Comment: @StefanMüller Did you get around to sharing your solution on GitLab? We're having a very similar problem and would appreciate seeing your results.

Comment: Hi Paul, my solution is here: https://gitlab.com/mueller44/bitcountryrouter But this will probably not work out of the box. I used a configuration of country2Language in additionalConfiguration.php. May be you can find some hints you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to merge language and country segments into one segment like "/de-AT/" with this approach?